# Can the function find_and_modify to run a half, if in update two keys?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

here used pymongo(Python):

Dict "update" contains two keys:

```
collection.find_and_modify(
    query={"_id": self.id},
    update={
        "$set": {"zzz.cur": xxx.chg},
        "$unset": {"zzz.bld": xxx.chg}
    }
)
```

Is there any chance that on error will be executed only "$set" ?
And the other("$unset") will fail?

Or find_and_modify always guarantee that both key execute?
I'm looking for a bug. Sometimes in my database remains is zzz.bld.
But I do not understand why. So I decided to clarify.

It seems that at the moment this function sometimes fails and runs only "$set"(my assumptions).

Comment: you should not be using findAndModify - just use a regular update.  The update will always be all or nothing - either both subfields will get updated or neither.

Answer (score 0):

`find_and_modify` is *supposed* to be atomic, since it [affects only a single document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/). From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method):

> When modifying a single document, both findAndModify() and the
>   update() method atomically update the document.

However I don't see any documentation explicitly stating whether the writes will be atomic or not when an error occurs.

But, the good news is that if you know how such an error might occur, it's pretty easy to create a test database with a multithreaded program that bombards the DB with such requests, and then simply see whether it's truly atomic or not.

Comment: >if you know how such an error|

The fact of the matter is that I don't know how to reproduce this situation. So I decided to clarify, could there be a problem in find_and_modify when two keys

Comment: I Do the tests using gevent.
Today the error was repeated 3 times.
But I never understood exactly how and why.

Comment: @Budulianin: Hmm I see. I don't know of any way that an update could fail halfway through either, but I haven't used MongoDB in a while, so I'm not really an expert on the minutiae of the implementation details.

Comment: all updates are all-or-nothing, so there is no way to have half the update only succeeded.  find_and_modify is not relevant here - the atomicity applies to all document writes.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky: I was just wondering if such a situation, when executed only $set(in find_and_modify)?

Comment: @Budulianin I'm not sure what you mean but regardless of what update does (one or more $set and/or other ops) it's *always* all or nothing.